# Content-Disposition Special Characters

Tags: utf-8, asp.net-mvc-2, internationalization, content-disposition

I have encountered an issue when trying to serve files with spanish tildes, related to the Content-Disposition encoding.

The file name is "qué hacés ahora.docx"

So far, the ASP.NET MVC way of serving files adds this header, which works fine only in Firefox:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8''qu%C3%A9%20hac%C3%A9s%20ahora.docx
```

I am using in the controller:

```
return File(path, "application/octet-stream", originalNameWithAccents);
```

This is not working in IE or Chrome.

So, I went and emailed myself the file as an attachment using GMail. Using firebug to see what is going on, the Content-Disposition google is sending back down is:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="=?UTF-8?B?cXXDqSBoYWPDqXMgYWhvcmEuZG9jeA==?="
```

Notice how the name is base64 encoded (cXXDqSBoYWPDqXMgYWhvcmEuZG9jeA==).

So, I have 2 questions so far:

1. Where is an specification for this?
2. Are there any known ways of serving this type filename using ASP.NET?

Comment: 1: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word and http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2047

Comment: Possibly dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http

Comment: In the meantime, the first format also works in Chrome and IE9. See also RFC 6266.

Comment: Yep, dup --- go to link ^above. Tadeusz A. Kadłubowski - thank you for pointing us in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the file name. File name like

```
 filename="=?utf-8?B?VGVzdG93eVBMSUvFgsSFw7PEh2FwaS5kb2N4?="
```

is encoded in base64 (VGVzdG93eVBMSUvFgsSFw7PEh2FwaS5kb2N4) charset utf-8 and oryginal file name:

```
 TestowyPLIKłąóćapi.docx
```

This is way to get file name:

```cs
string cdString = "attachment; filename=\"=?UTF-8?B?cXXDqSBoYWPDqXMgYWhvcmEuZG9jeA==?=\"";
string filename;

System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue val;
if (System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(cdString, out val))
    fileName = val.FileName.Replace("\"", "");
else
    throw new Exception("...");
```

And

```
fileName = "qué hacés ahora.docx"
```